# Waiting for an asynchronous call to complete first and then proceed in Java

Tags: java, asynchronous, synchronous

I have a situation wherein I call a method which in turn triggers a asynchronous HTTP REST call(sends the status later to another endpoint) before it proceeds further. I want the method to wait until i get the response back to the endpoint, check the status i got and proceed further. I am looking for a feasible solution in Java. Any pseudo code or implementation will be helpful

saw similar case @ [Lightweight way of waiting for a group of asynchronous Java calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937609/lightweight-way-of-waiting-for-a-group-of-asynchronous-java-calls) but not much idea about the same whether it is easy to implement.

**Implementation details**

I have JAX-RS endpoint to handle the async response as below

```
@POST
@Path("/status")
@Consumes("application/xml")
public Response processConfigStatus(@Context UriInfo uriInfo, ConfigStatus configStatus)
{
   // process Status got from the async REST call
   return ResponseHelper.createNoContentResponse();
}
```

**Class which handles and processes**

```
Class ProcessData{

  public void updateData()
    checktStatus(uri);
    update();// should wait untill the processConfigStatus() endpoint gives status
  }

  private  checktStatus(String uri){
     // makes a REST call to a URI using a JAX-RS webclient or a httpclient this returns HTTP 200 or 204 code immediatley. And then the Server process the request asynchronously and gives back the status to JAX-RS endpoint(/status).
     post(uri);
  }

}
```

**Method call from another Class**

```
ProcessData pd = new ProcessData()
pd.updateData();
```

Comment: and some code from your side is also welcome

Answer (score 4):

How about using a [CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html)?

> A synchronization aid that allows one or more threads to wait until a set of operations being performed in other threads completes.

Answer (score 0):

Just as in the link you provided, you'll have to implement a way to simply keep track of how many async calls are stilling waiting for a response and wait until that count is zero.

```
count = numAsyncCalls
..calling all of the RESTful services here (each call must have some sort of callback to decrement 'count' variable above..
while (count > 0)
   wait around
```

The use of the CountDownLatch in your link looks pretty much the same as my pseudo-code

Comment: @Bozho, added the code iam planning to implement.                                                   @jerluc, i havent worked on the callbacks in java, for the above implementation of mine how we can have this or from the processConfigStatus() REST handler i might need to call a method in ProcessData class to give the status.